# Is there a way to know which packages are being installed by pip inside setup.py?

Tags: python, pymongo, setup.py, bson, requirements.txt

I need bson utilities in my python module, so I found this awesome module - https://github.com/py-bson/bson, which answers my needs exactly.

Then, I added my module to requirements.txt of another project, but on the same requirements.txt there was pymongo, and I found out that it makes the pymongo corrupted by overriding pymongo's built-in bson, which causes import errors in pymongo.

I found this issue https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/29 which concluded that those 2 packages shouldn't live together, so I'm trying to figure out if I can somehow, on the setup.py understand if I'm being installed with pymongo so I can skip the installation of bson and used the built-in of pymonogo?

I know I can check if pymongo is already installed in the setup.py, but I cannot know for sure that after my module is being installed that one of the next modules in the requirements is not pymongo. Also, I would like to avoid directly reading the requirements file because I want to be able to support nested requirements.txt if needed.